# I am looking for a sql query to exclude records in sql that are not a filename and is liget file's extension

Tags: sql, regex

sample data is like below(5 rows):

```
e:\deploy\applications\intel management engine interface and serial over lan driver (sol) driver 7.1.2.1041v2\me_sw\mewmiprov\me\cim_schema\system\cim_computersystemdma.mof
c:\$recycle.bin\s-1-5-21-3125639655-2069970247-2443061104-29869\$iqzvjd6.jpg
c:\users\asdf\music\the cranberries\no need to argue\02 i can't be with you.mp3
e:\oracle\epm\docs\epm~1.111\wa_user\about_navigating_data_objects.html
Marijuana; Suicide; ass; butt; don’t say anything; drug; kick; knife; knives; marijuana; murder; naked; opiate; party; prick; scam; sex; smoke; smoke a joint; smoking; sneak; speculation; stabbed; stoned; suck; tripping
```

Apparently the last one is NOT a legitimate file and the others are.
Can anyone help? Thank you very much

Comment: What is your RDBMs and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: What qualifies/disqualifies a filename and extension?

Answer (score -1):

Does this help?

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE FileNameColumn NOT LIKE '_:\%.%'
```